# how to convert doc file and pdf file to image file?

Tags: java, image, pdf, doc

What is the best open source java api for converting of doc and pdf file into any image file? 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question already has multiple answers here on SO. Just search for "doc file to image" or "PDF to image".

But in short, there are many different methods. The main ones seem to be:

1. To use a dedicated API, made specifically for this task (PDF Box seems to be popular).
2. Parse the Doc or PDF file and rasterize it to turn it into an image (what the APIs do?).

OR

3. Install a printer-emulator driver, open word/PDF invisibly, and use the printer-emulator to "print" the document, but instead of sending the bytes to an actual, physical printer, the emulator prints to a new PDF or image file.

Comment: Broken link on the "here" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437394/java-library-for-converting-word-documents-to-pdfs-or-images is not found

Comment: @antoine Fixed (+Update). Thanks for the heads up! =)